# How to get current host and port in micronaut?

Tags: java, micronaut

I'm trying to get current host and port in micronaut application. how do i get it in dynamic manner?

I've tried @Value("{micronaut.server.host}") and @Value("{micronaut.server.port}") but doesn't work.

```
@Controller("/some/endpoint")
class SomeController {
    @Value("{micronaut.server.host}")
    protected String host;

    @Value("{micronaut.server.port}")
    protected Long port;
}
```

Comment: I haven't used the service in a while, but could you try:    protected String host = environment.getProperty("micronaut.server.host", String.class); protected Long port= environment.getProperty("micronaut.server.port", Long.class);

Comment: It works! Thank you. I see it now. So @Value is used only to get configuration value we specified in application.yml?

Comment: I'm glad it worked @below-1

Comment: As far as I know @Value has many purposes but Micronaut suggests getting port and server host values though the environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it.  One is to retrieve them from the `EmbeddedServer`.

```
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer;

@Controller("/demo")
public class DemoController {

    protected final String host;

    protected final int port;

    public DemoController(EmbeddedServer embeddedServer) {
        host = embeddedServer.getHost();
        port = embeddedServer.getPort();
    }

    @Get("/")
    public HttpStatus index() {
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it looks cleaner to me. Thank you

Comment: There are some pluses and minuses to different approaches, some of it not a big deal either way.  To me, this feels kind of right if what I really want to know is "What host and port is the server running on?" as opposed to "What are the values of the `micronaut.server.host` and `micronaut.server.port` config settings?".  If I want to know what port the server is running on, asking the server seems to make sense.  Going to the config settings is fine too.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake. As @JaredWare says, we should use `Environment` to retrieve the property of the application.

```
@Controller("/some/endpoint")
class SomeController {
   @Inject
   protected Environment env;

   @Get
   public String someMethod () {
       Optional<String> host = this.env.getProperty("micronaut.server.host", String.class);
       return host.orElse("defaultHost");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The original way you had it is the same as retrieving it from the `environment`. You were just missing the `$` in your `@Value` annotation.

`@Value("${micronaut.server.host}")` is equivalent to `env.getProperty("micronaut.server.host", String.class)`

That will retrieve whatever is configured. If instead you want to retrieve it from the embedded server itself you could do that as well since the actual port may be different from the configured port. That is because it's possible to simply not configure the port or because the configured value is -1 which indicates a random port.